# Is it possible to reverse engineer an artificial Gödel number encoding that would prove a famous question?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

My understanding of Gödel's numbering (?) is that you can use it to uniquely define a mathematical symbol or concept, that encodes the steps to getting there in a number.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering

> This allowed Gödel to show a correspondence between statements about natural numbers and statements about the provability of theorems about natural numbers, the key observation of the proof

Can a number be altered, and then it's derivation be worked backwards to find what would need to be different to 'justify' that change?

Say we wanted to prove P=NP, and we can represent P and $G_{n1}$ and NP as $G_{n2}$, and look at the difference in prime factorisation for each.

Could we observe that to *set* them equal we'd need to make a change to one of the factors?

For instance, if it turned out, actually, $13^9\times G_{n1} = 193^4\times G_{n2}$, that is to set the two concepts as equal we'd need to change their derivation by a factors of $\frac{193^4}{13^9}$ and figure out either how to make that change, or if it meant we could agree on a subset of cases where P=NP.

(n.b. I'm not specifying P=NP as it's vital to the question, it's just the first big topic where this idea would work that came to mind.)

Comment: I've had this on my mind since I first heard of Gödel numbers on Numberphile, but I'm not sure I've phrase this super clearly.

Comment: For any interesting mathematical statement, the Gödel number is going to fill several pages. It's good for theory, but not a practical way to approach mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing equality of statements and logical equivalences.

The Gödel numbers encode nothing more than the statements, so trying to tweak one statement (P) into the other statement (NP) is usually not the way to prove things.

For example, you wouldn't try to prove Fermat's Last Theorem by looking at the statement and seeing how to tweak it to say "true".

Comment: I must admit, I didn't realize there was a difference in "equality of statements and logical equivalences"... Is there anyway to expand on that

Comment: The statement $P_1(n): \exists k, n = k + k$ is equivalent to the statement $P_2(n): \exists k, n = 2 \times k$ (both are saying that $n$ is even), although they are not the same statement.

Comment: ahh so you couldn't get the Gödel number of $2\times k$ to match $k+k$? That would an insightful example to add to the answer, in an [edit].

Comment: As I said in my answer, the Gödel number is not some magical device, it's just a way to encode formulas into numbers. So you're essentially asking whether you can get the formula $2 \times k$ to match $k + k$.

Comment: Please continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics).